# Move a 3D Vector on a plane and keep the magnitude

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, 3d

I have a `Vector3(x,y,z)` and I want to "rotate" (don't know the correct term) on a plane (`Y=0`).

I got a good result (not that good) if I just update the `vector.y` value to `0`. In that way x, y and z have the good direction but his magnitude is lower (I just made a projection, not the good rotation).

I don't know I'm understood so I made an ugly draw:

[image]

Currently I have the orange vector on result, and I want the brown one (who start at the origin)

How can I get the good `x` and `z` to get the same vector with `y=0` ?

Comment: If you want to be able to handle general rotations, what you want is a rotation matrix. One that works for right-handed systems (like yours) is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions
at the section called Conversion Formulae between formalisms under Euler angles (z-y'-x'' intrinsic) $\rightarrow$ rotation matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
New.x = old.x * Sqrt((old.x^2 + old.y^2 + old.z^2) / (old.x^2 + old.z^2))
New.z = old.z * Sqrt((old.x^2 + old.y^2 + old.z^2) / (old.x^2 + old.z^2))
New.y = 0
```

Caveat: if `old.x = 0` and `old.z = 0`, it is unclear to which vector on the plane you want to map to. And the pseudo-code above will give division by zero. You will have to deal with that special case separately.